# How to Bind to a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

My requirement is that I need to bind a user control to a Property of an object,whose list is enclosed within a different object and the list of the second object is set as the ItemsSource.

Example

```
class A
{
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

class B
{
    public List<A> aObjectList;
}

List<B> bObjectsList = new List<B>();    
userControl.ItemSource = bObjectsList;
userControl.Content = new Binding("Name");
```

How do I do the above thing???

Comment: Do you want to flatten the list? (Create one list of `A` items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you want to allow the GUI to update itself when something changes, you should use an implementation of `NotifyCollectionChanged`, for instance the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

The XAML would look like this:

```
   <ItemsControl Name="userControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding aObjectsList}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

That is, assuming that your UserControl is an ItemsControl. Then in the code do:

```
 userControl.ItemsSource = bObjectsList;
```

A good idea would be to look at the MVVM Pattern. This will provide a more structured solution, allowing things like modification notices etc.

[Here is a good article to get you started.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is not real clear but I think this is what you are asking.  You would bind to

```
    bObjectsList[index].aObjectList
```

In a master detail you use the following syntax

```
    ItemsSource="{binding ElementName=cbbObjectsList path=SelectedItem.aObjectList}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are many interpretations of what you're trying to do.  If you want to flatten the list, you use the [SelectMany LINQ method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).

```
List<B> bObjectsList = new List<B>();    
userControl.ItemSource = bObjectsList.SelectMany(b => b.aObjectList);
userControl.Content = new Binding("Name");
```

If the contents of A/B are changing, you'll probably use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) on them and react accordingly.